# Will gameObject.Destroy() remove a referanced gameObject in a List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I have a:

```
List<GameObject> brickList;
```

and every time I instantiate an instance of the brick(which is a prefabed gameObject) I will put that into the list:

```
brickList.add(Instantiate(brick, transform, Quaternion.identity));
```

And if I destroy a brick in the List by `GameObject.Destroy()`:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Brick")){
         Destroy(collision.gameObject);
   }
}
```

Will that make the reference in the `brickList` point to `null` and take the destroyed brick out of the rendering system?

Comment: No, you need to remove it from the list.

Answer (score 7):

The brick will no longer be rendered. The game object and components on the game object will be in a "destroyed" state. If you compare the game object to `null` (`brickList[0] == null`) it will return `true` because of operator overloading - even though the object isn't *really* `null`. Most properties and methods called on Unity's components will give you an exception if the component has been destroyed.
If you want the reference in the list to disappear, you will have to remove it yourself.

Comment: Great coverage! TIL, +1! Is there a way to un-destroy an item after destroying it then, if it's still there and not really null but in a destroyed state?

Comment: Basically the operator overloading tells you "Unity is from now on unaware of the existence of this object". So there is no real way to undestroy it.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Brick")){
         Destroy(collision.gameObject);
         if (brickList.Containt(collision.gameObject)) {
             brickList.Remove(collision.gameObject);
         }
   }
}
```

Yay remove it because it will null in list.